# .net rest API vs Node.js vs other platform for Asynchronous Non Blocking App?

Tags: .net, node.js, rest

Given a choice between .net rest API vs Node.js vs other platform, what would you choose as the API platform for building a asynchronous, non-blocking app that should handle millions of concurrent requests and why ?

Comment: The one you're most comfortable with, really. ASP.NET Core and NodeJS (especially via V8 upgrades) seem to be pushing higher performance as time goes by. If you're just starting out in both cases, I'd go with whatever stack you feel most in line with your long term goals. Sorry to be so vague, but realistically, you should be fine either way you go.

Answer (score 0):

i don't wanna say it depends.  node.js guaranteed single thread.However i would choose .net because i like to use vs and intellisense perfectly helpful. I'm working with .net on my professional life i used to it. I worked with  node.js a little bit there are many many npm package to help you. So if you used to it some of these languages choose that one.On the other way If you start to develop your self newly i suggest you use node.js. There is no big big perfomans difference between them and you really don't need this type of perfomans. Which one is easy to use choose it.

in addition

Stackowerflow using Mvc .net do you feel any perfomans problem with that maybe they need some more machine. However node.js developer not too much in the world even they say is not. Hardware is Cheap, Programmers are Expensive. If you want to make an app and wanna be rich or wanna create a company you will think like that